# How to copy an executable with all needed libraries?

Tags: linux, dependencies, shared-libraries, executable

I have two fairly identical (Linux-) systems but one with just a minimum set of packages installed. On one system I have a running (binary/ELF) executable which I want to copy over to the other system (with the minimum setup).

Now I need a way to copy all needed shared libraries as well. Currently I start the application on the source system and then go through the output of

```
lsof | grep <PID>
```

or

```
ldd <FILE>
```

to get a list of all libraries currently loaded by the application and copy them over manually.

**Now my question is:** before I start to automate this approach and run into lots of little problems and end up with yet another reinvented wheel - Is there a tool which already automates this for me? The tool I'm dreaming of right now would work like this:

```
$ pack-bin-for-copy <MY_EXE>
```

which creates a `.tgz` with all needed shared libraries needed to run this executable.

or

```
$ cp-bin <MY_EXE> user@target:/target/path/
```

which would just copy the binary once..

**Note:** I do NOT need a way to professionally *deploy* an application (via RPM/apt/etc.). I'm looking for a 'just for now' solution.

Comment: In my opinion your approach with `ldd` is the right one for manual preparation of a delivery package. Besides that, if you're the owner of the built SW, you should also be able to define what non-linking relevant files are important and should be included: configuration files, scripts, runtime loaded libraries/plugins etc.

Comment: hint: many distro's initrd generators have this function.

Comment: also https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10238/ and https://h3manth.com/content/copying-shared-library-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

One tool that does something similar to what you suggest is [linuxdeploy](https://github.com/linuxdeploy/linuxdeploy). While the tool is intended to ease the creation of an AppImage (see [here](https://appimage.org/) for more information), it will pack your executable with any dependencies into a directory. Then you can just create a 'tgz' file of that directory instead of an AppImage.

Answer (score 0):

`ldd` usuage is correct if you also enable `-Wl,--no-dynamic-lookup` at link time.